# Get Internal id for country list in NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 by passing the country code

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Invested lot of time to get the internal Ids of country list in NetSuite, could not find a standard way. if anyone knows any better way to do it please post in the comment

```
function getCountryInternalId(code){
        var internalId = '';
        var idPlusName = {"Afghanistan":"3","Aland Islands":"247","Albania":"6","Algeria":"62","American Samoa":"12","Andorra":"1","Angola":"9","Anguilla":"5","Antarctica":"10","Antigua and Barbuda":"4","Argentina":"11","Armenia":"7","Aruba":"15","Australia":"14","Austria":"13","Azerbaijan":"16","Bahamas":"31","Bahrain":"23","Bangladesh":"19","Barbados":"18","Belarus":"35","Belgium":"20","Belize":"36","Benin":"25","Bermuda":"27","Bhutan":"32","Bolivia":"29","Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba":"250","Bosnia and Herzegovina":"17","Botswana":"34","Bouvet Island":"33","Brazil":"30","British Indian Ocean Territory":"106","Brunei Darussalam":"28","Bulgaria":"22","Burkina Faso":"21","Burundi":"24","Cambodia":"117","Cameroon":"46","Canada":"37","Canary Islands":"249","Cape Verde":"53","Cayman Islands":"124","Central African Republic":"40","Ceuta and Melilla":"248","Chad":"212","Chile":"45","China":"47","Christmas Island":"54","Cocos (Keeling) Islands":"38","Colombia":"48","Comoros":"119","Congo, Democratic Republic of":"39","Congo, Republic of":"41","Cook Islands":"44","Costa Rica":"49","Cote d'Ivoire":"43","Croatia/Hrvatska":"98","Cuba":"52","Curaçao":"251","Cyprus":"55","Czech Republic":"56","Denmark":"59","Djibouti":"58","Dominica":"60","Dominican Republic":"61","East Timor":"221","Ecuador":"63","Egypt":"65","El Salvador":"208","Equatorial Guinea":"88","Eritrea":"67","Estonia":"64","Ethiopia":"69","Falkland Islands":"72","Faroe Islands":"74","Fiji":"71","Finland":"70","France":"75","French Guiana":"80","French Polynesia":"175","French Southern Territories":"213","Gabon":"76","Gambia":"85","Georgia":"79","Germany":"57","Ghana":"82","Gibraltar":"83","Greece":"89","Greenland":"84","Grenada":"78","Guadeloupe":"87","Guam":"92","Guatemala":"91","Guernsey":"81","Guinea":"86","Guinea-Bissau":"93","Guyana":"94","Haiti":"99","Heard and McDonald Islands":"96","Holy See (City Vatican State)":"233","Honduras":"97","Hong Kong":"95","Hungary":"100","Iceland":"109","India":"105","Indonesia":"101","Iran (Islamic Republic of)":"108","Iraq":"107","Ireland":"102","Isle of Man":"104","Israel":"103","Italy":"110","Jamaica":"112","Japan":"114","Jersey":"111","Jordan":"113","Kazakhstan":"125","Kenya":"115","Kiribati":"118","Korea, Democratic People's Republic":"121","Korea, Republic of":"122","Kosovo":"254","Kuwait":"123","Kyrgyzstan":"116","Lao People's Democratic Republic":"126","Latvia":"135","Lebanon":"127","Lesotho":"132","Liberia":"131","Libya":"136","Liechtenstein":"129","Lithuania":"133","Luxembourg":"134","Macau":"148","Macedonia":"144","Madagascar":"142","Malawi":"156","Malaysia":"158","Maldives":"155","Mali":"145","Malta":"153","Marshall Islands":"143","Martinique":"150","Mauritania":"151","Mauritius":"154","Mayotte":"243","Mexico":"157","Micronesia, Federal State of":"73","Moldova, Republic of":"139","Monaco":"138","Mongolia":"147","Montenegro":"140","Montserrat":"152","Morocco":"137","Mozambique":"159","Myanmar (Burma)":"146","Namibia":"160","Nauru":"169","Nepal":"168","Netherlands":"166","Netherlands Antilles (Deprecated)":"8","New Caledonia":"161","New Zealand":"171","Nicaragua":"165","Niger":"162","Nigeria":"164","Niue":"170","Norfolk Island":"163","Northern Mariana Islands":"149","Norway":"167","Oman":"172","Pakistan":"178","Palau":"185","Panama":"173","Papua New Guinea":"176","Paraguay":"186","Peru":"174","Philippines":"177","Pitcairn Island":"181","Poland":"179","Portugal":"184","Puerto Rico":"182","Qatar":"187","Reunion Island":"188","Romania":"189","Russian Federation":"190","Rwanda":"191","Saint Barthélemy":"26","Saint Helena":"198","Saint Kitts and Nevis":"120","Saint Lucia":"128","Saint Martin":"141","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines":"234","Samoa":"241","San Marino":"203","Sao Tome and Principe":"207","Saudi Arabia":"192","Senegal":"204","Serbia":"50","Serbia and Montenegro (Deprecated)":"51","Seychelles":"194","Sierra Leone":"202","Singapore":"197","Sint Maarten":"252","Slovak Republic":"201","Slovenia":"199","Solomon Islands":"193","Somalia":"205","South Africa":"244","South Georgia":"90","South Sudan":"253","Spain":"68","Sri Lanka":"130","St. Pierre and Miquelon":"180","State of Palestine":"183","Sudan":"195","Suriname":"206","Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands":"200","Swaziland":"210","Sweden":"196","Switzerland":"42","Syrian Arab Republic":"209","Taiwan":"225","Tajikistan":"216","Tanzania":"226","Thailand":"215","Togo":"214","Tokelau":"217","Tonga":"220","Trinidad and Tobago":"223","Tunisia":"219","Turkey":"222","Turkmenistan":"218","Turks and Caicos Islands":"211","Tuvalu":"224","Uganda":"228","Ukraine":"227","United Arab Emirates":"2","United Kingdom":"77","United States":"230","Uruguay":"231","US Minor Outlying Islands":"229","Uzbekistan":"232","Vanuatu":"239","Venezuela":"235","Vietnam":"238","Virgin Islands (British)":"236","Virgin Islands (USA)":"237","Wallis and Futuna":"240","Western Sahara":"66","Yemen":"242","Zambia":"245","Zimbabwe":"246"};
        var codePlusName =  {"AF":"Afghanistan","AX":"Aland Islands","AL":"Albania","DZ":"Algeria","AS":"American Samoa","AD":"Andorra","AO":"Angola","AI":"Anguilla","AQ":"Antarctica","AG":"Antigua and Barbuda","AR":"Argentina","AM":"Armenia","AW":"Aruba","AU":"Australia","AT":"Austria","AZ":"Azerbaijan","BS":"Bahamas","BH":"Bahrain","BD":"Bangladesh","BB":"Barbados","BY":"Belarus","BE":"Belgium","BZ":"Belize","BJ":"Benin","BM":"Bermuda","BT":"Bhutan","BO":"Bolivia","BQ":"Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba","BA":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","BW":"Botswana","BV":"Bouvet Island","BR":"Brazil","IO":"British Indian Ocean Territory","BN":"Brunei Darussalam","BG":"Bulgaria","BF":"Burkina Faso","BI":"Burundi","KH":"Cambodia","CM":"Cameroon","CA":"Canada","IC":"Canary Islands","CV":"Cape Verde","KY":"Cayman Islands","CF":"Central African Republic","EA":"Ceuta and Melilla","TD":"Chad","CL":"Chile","CN":"China","CX":"Christmas Island","CC":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","CO":"Colombia","KM":"Comoros","CD":"Congo, Democratic Republic of","CG":"Congo, Republic of","CK":"Cook Islands","CR":"Costa Rica","CI":"Cote d'Ivoire","HR":"Croatia/Hrvatska","CU":"Cuba","CW":"CuraÃ§ao","CY":"Cyprus","CZ":"Czech Republic","DK":"Denmark","DJ":"Djibouti","DM":"Dominica","DO":"Dominican Republic","TL":"East Timor","EC":"Ecuador","EG":"Egypt","SV":"El Salvador","GQ":"Equatorial Guinea","ER":"Eritrea","EE":"Estonia","ET":"Ethiopia","FK":"Falkland Islands","FO":"Faroe Islands","FJ":"Fiji","FI":"Finland","FR":"France","GF":"French Guiana","PF":"French Polynesia","TF":"French Southern Territories","GA":"Gabon","GM":"Gambia","GE":"Georgia","DE":"Germany","GH":"Ghana","GI":"Gibraltar","GR":"Greece","GL":"Greenland","GD":"Grenada","GP":"Guadeloupe","GU":"Guam","GT":"Guatemala","GG":"Guernsey","GN":"Guinea","GW":"Guinea-Bissau","GY":"Guyana","HT":"Haiti","HM":"Heard and McDonald Islands","VA":"Holy See (City Vatican State)","HN":"Honduras","HK":"Hong Kong","HU":"Hungary","IS":"Iceland","IN":"India","ID":"Indonesia","IR":"Iran (Islamic Republic of)","IQ":"Iraq","IE":"Ireland","IM":"Isle of Man","IL":"Israel","IT":"Italy","JM":"Jamaica","JP":"Japan","JE":"Jersey","JO":"Jordan","KZ":"Kazakhstan","KE":"Kenya","KI":"Kiribati","KP":"Korea, Democratic People's Republic","KR":"Korea, Republic of","XK":"Kosovo","KW":"Kuwait","KG":"Kyrgyzstan","LA":"Lao People's Democratic Republic","LV":"Latvia","LB":"Lebanon","LS":"Lesotho","LR":"Liberia","LY":"Libya","LI":"Liechtenstein","LT":"Lithuania","LU":"Luxembourg","MO":"Macau","MK":"Macedonia","MG":"Madagascar","MW":"Malawi","MY":"Malaysia","MV":"Maldives","ML":"Mali","MT":"Malta","MH":"Marshall Islands","MQ":"Martinique","MR":"Mauritania","MU":"Mauritius","YT":"Mayotte","MX":"Mexico","FM":"Micronesia, Federal State of","MD":"Moldova, Republic of","MC":"Monaco","MN":"Mongolia","ME":"Montenegro","MS":"Montserrat","MA":"Morocco","MZ":"Mozambique","MM":"Myanmar (Burma)","NA":"Namibia","NR":"Nauru","NP":"Nepal","NL":"Netherlands","AN":"Netherlands Antilles (Deprecated)","NC":"New Caledonia","NZ":"New Zealand","NI":"Nicaragua","NE":"Niger","NG":"Nigeria","NU":"Niue","NF":"Norfolk Island","MP":"Northern Mariana Islands","NO":"Norway","OM":"Oman","PK":"Pakistan","PW":"Palau","PS":"Palestinian Territories","PA":"Panama","PG":"Papua New Guinea","PY":"Paraguay","PE":"Peru","PH":"Philippines","PN":"Pitcairn Island","PL":"Poland","PT":"Portugal","PR":"Puerto Rico","QA":"Qatar","RE":"Reunion Island","RO":"Romania","RU":"Russian Federation","RW":"Rwanda","BL":"Saint BarthÃ©lemy","SH":"Saint Helena","KN":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","LC":"Saint Lucia","MF":"Saint Martin","VC":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","WS":"Samoa","SM":"San Marino","ST":"Sao Tome and Principe","SA":"Saudi Arabia","SN":"Senegal","RS":"Serbia","CS":"Serbia and Montenegro (Deprecated)","SC":"Seychelles","SL":"Sierra Leone","SG":"Singapore","SX":"Sint Maarten","SK":"Slovak Republic","SI":"Slovenia","SB":"Solomon Islands","SO":"Somalia","ZA":"South Africa","GS":"South Georgia","SS":"South Sudan","ES":"Spain","LK":"Sri Lanka","PM":"St. Pierre and Miquelon","SD":"Sudan","SR":"Suriname","SJ":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","SZ":"Swaziland","SE":"Sweden","CH":"Switzerland","SY":"Syrian Arab Republic","TW":"Taiwan","TJ":"Tajikistan","TZ":"Tanzania","TH":"Thailand","TG":"Togo","TK":"Tokelau","TO":"Tonga","TT":"Trinidad and Tobago","TN":"Tunisia","TR":"Turkey","TM":"Turkmenistan","TC":"Turks and Caicos Islands","TV":"Tuvalu","UG":"Uganda","UA":"Ukraine","AE":"United Arab Emirates","GB":"United Kingdom (GB)","US":"United States","UY":"Uruguay","UM":"US Minor Outlying Islands","UZ":"Uzbekistan","VU":"Vanuatu","VE":"Venezuela","VN":"Vietnam","VG":"Virgin Islands (British)","VI":"Virgin Islands (USA)","WF":"Wallis and Futuna","EH":"Western Sahara","YE":"Yemen","ZM":"Zambia","ZW":"Zimbabwe"};

        var name = codePlusName[code];
        internalId = idPlusName[name]
        log.debug({title:'Country-internalId',
            details:internalId
        });
        return internalId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in Suite answers, Normally when we look at
Setup>company>countries>open any country and check the url there would be ID, that only shows the Alphabetical ID.

In Suite answers check the Answer ID's: 71731 & 38434
or links below
https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/71731/kw/country%20internal%20id's

https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/38434/kw/country%20internal%20id&/related/1

```
Country Name    Country Code    Internal ID
Afghanistan AF  3
Aland Islands   AX  247
Albania AL  6
Algeria DZ  62
American Samoa  AS  12
Andorra AD  1
Angola  AO  9
Anguilla    AI  5
Antarctica  AQ  10
Antigua and Barbuda AG  4
Argentina   AR  11
Armenia AM  7
Aruba   AW  15
Australia   AU  14
Austria AT  13
Azerbaijan  AZ  16
Bahamas BS  31
Bahrain BH  23
Bangladesh  BD  19
Barbados    BB  18
Belarus BY  35
Belgium BE  20
Belize  BZ  36
Benin   BJ  25
Bermuda BM  27
Bhutan  BT  32
Bolivia BO  29
Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba   BQ  250
Bosnia and Herzegovina  BA  17
Botswana    BW  34
Bouvet Island   BV  33
Brazil  BR  30
British Indian Ocean Territory  IO  106
Brunei Darussalam   BN  28
Bulgaria    BG  22
Burkina Faso    BF  21
Burundi BI  24
Cambodia    KH  117
Cameroon    CM  46
Canada  CA  37
Canary Islands  IC  249
Cape Verde  CV  53
Cayman Islands  KY  124
Central African Republic    CF  40
Ceuta and Melilla   EA  248
Chad    TD  212
Chile   CL  45
China   CN  47
Christmas Island    CX  54
Cocos (Keeling) Islands CC  38
Colombia    CO  48
Comoros KM  119
Congo, Democratic Republic of   CD  39
Congo, Republic of  CG  41
Cook Islands    CK  44
Costa Rica  CR  49
Cote d\u0027Ivoire  CI  43
Croatia/Hrvatska    HR  98
Cuba    CU  52
Curaçao CW  251
Cyprus  CY  55
Czech Republic  CZ  56
Denmark DK  59
Djibouti    DJ  58
Dominica    DM  60
Dominican Republic  DO  61
East Timor  TP  221
Ecuador EC  63
Egypt   EG  65
El Salvador SV  208
Equatorial Guinea   GQ  88
Eritrea ER  67
Estonia EE  64
Ethiopia    ET  69
Falkland Islands    FK  72
Faroe Islands   FO  74
Fiji    FJ  71
Finland FI  70
France  FR  75
French Guiana   GF  80
French Polynesia    PF  175
French Southern Territories TF  213
Gabon   GA  76
Gambia  GM  85
Georgia GE  79
Germany DE  57
Ghana   GH  82
Gibraltar   GI  83
Greece  GR  89
Greenland   GL  84
Grenada GD  78
Guadeloupe  GP  87
Guam    GU  92
Guatemala   GT  91
Guernsey    GG  81
Guinea  GN  86
Guinea-Bissau   GW  93
Guyana  GY  94
Haiti   HT  99
Heard and McDonald Islands  HM  96
Holy See (City Vatican State)   VA  233
Honduras    HN  97
Hong Kong   HK  95
Hungary HU  100
Iceland IS  109
India   IN  105
Indonesia   ID  101
Iran (Islamic Republic of)  IR  108
Iraq    IQ  107
Ireland IE  102
Isle of Man IM  104
Israel  IL  103
Italy   IT  110
Jamaica JM  112
Japan   JP  114
Jersey  JE  111
Jordan  JO  113
Kazakhstan  KZ  125
Kenya   KE  115
Kiribati    KI  118
Korea, Democratic People\u0027s Republic    KP  121
Korea, Republic of  KR  122
Kosovo  XK  254
Kuwait  KW  123
Kyrgyzstan  KG  116
Lao People\u0027s Democratic Republic   LA  126
Latvia  LV  135
Lebanon LB  127
Lesotho LS  132
Liberia LR  131
Libya   LY  136
Liechtenstein   LI  129
Lithuania   LT  133
Luxembourg  LU  134
Macau   MO  148
Macedonia   MK  144
Madagascar  MG  142
Malawi  MW  156
Malaysia    MY  158
Maldives    MV  155
Mali    ML  145
Malta   MT  153
Marshall Islands    MH  143
Martinique  MQ  150
Mauritania  MR  151
Mauritius   MU  154
Mayotte YT  243
Mexico  MX  157
Micronesia, Federal State of    FM  73
Moldova, Republic of    MD  139
Monaco  MC  138
Mongolia    MN  147
Montenegro  ME  140
Montserrat  MS  152
Morocco MA  137
Mozambique  MZ  159
Myanmar (Burma) MM  146
Namibia NA  160
Nauru   NR  169
Nepal   NP  168
Netherlands NL  166
Netherlands Antilles (Deprecated)       8
New Caledonia   NC  161
New Zealand NZ  171
Nicaragua   NI  165
Niger   NE  162
Nigeria NG  164
Niue    NU  170
Norfolk Island  NF  163
Northern Mariana Islands    MP  149
Norway  NO  167
Oman    OM  172
Pakistan    PK  178
Palau   PW  185
Panama  PA  173
Papua New Guinea    PG  176
Paraguay    PY  186
Peru    PE  174
Philippines PH  177
Pitcairn Island PN  181
Poland  PL  179
Portugal    PT  184
Puerto Rico PR  182
Qatar   QA  187
Reunion Island  RE  188
Romania RO  189
Russian Federation  RU  190
Rwanda  RW  191
Saint Barthélemy    BL  26
Saint Helena    SH  198
Saint Kitts and Nevis   KN  120
Saint Lucia LC  128
Saint Martin    MF  141
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines    VC  234
Samoa   WS  241
San Marino  SM  203
Sao Tome and Principe   ST  207
Saudi Arabia    SA  192
Senegal SN  204
Serbia  RS  50

Seychelles  SC  194
Sierra Leone    SL  202
Singapore   SG  197
Sint Maarten    SX  252
Slovak Republic SK  201
Slovenia    SI  199
Solomon Islands SB  193
Somalia SO  205
South Africa    ZA  244
South Georgia   GS  90
South Sudan SS  253
Spain   ES  68
Sri Lanka   LK  130
St. Pierre and Miquelon PS  180
State of Palestine  PM  183
Sudan   SD  195
Suriname    SR  206
Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands  SJ  200
Swaziland   SZ  210
Sweden  SE  196
Switzerland CH  42
Syrian Arab Republic    SY  209
Taiwan  TW  225
Tajikistan  TJ  216
Tanzania    TZ  226
Thailand    TH  215
Togo    TG  214
Tokelau TK  217
Tonga   TO  220
Trinidad and Tobago TT  223
Tunisia TN  219
Turkey  TR  222
Turkmenistan    TM  218
Turks and Caicos Islands    TC  211
Tuvalu  TV  224
Uganda  UG  228
Ukraine UA  227
United Arab Emirates    AE  2
United Kingdom  GB  77
United States   US  230
Uruguay UY  231
US Minor Outlying Islands   UM  229
Uzbekistan  UZ  232
Vanuatu VU  239
Venezuela   VE  235
Vietnam VN  238
Virgin Islands (British)    VG  236
Virgin Islands (USA)    VI  237
Wallis and Futuna   WF  240
Western Sahara  EH  66
Yemen   YE  242
Zambia  ZM  245
Zimbabwe    ZW  246
```